# ArrayList losing items

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Is there a reason why an ArrayList would just lose items? I have an ArrayList that holds ArrayLists which holds Integers. There are about 32 items in each. Later when I need to call the ArrayList the items are missing except the last one. There are still 32 items, but they're empty.

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [-16323110, -16688166, -14978279, -837220, -11002320, -4136419, -13118245, -5370572, -11382698, -13140399, -13754890, -8184649, -11711035, -11668025, -12910969, -11058211, -9974559, -9665946, -12513105, -14320755, -16332438, -7673092, -13016023, -15454286, -12413148, -9780316, -2553149, -3313219, -10953060, -940790, -11989718, -12189591]]
```

I'm able to read it once and everything is there... but later when i call it again it's gone. I'm not removing anything. What is happening here?

I cant post my original code but heres a mock up.

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

private void makeArray() {
for(int i = 0; i<= _height - 1; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int ii = 0; ii <= _width - 1; ii++) {
                row.add(ii);    
            }
            myArray.add(row);
        }
}

private void readArray() {
ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for(int a = 0; a <= _height - 1; a++) {
                row.clear();
                row = myArray.get(a);

                for(int aa = 0; aa <= _width - 1; aa++) {
                    int c = row.get(aa);
//stuff
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You are calling row.clear(); (why?)

Comment: Have you tried debugging by stepping through the loops to see if the data ever gets added correctly to begin with?

Comment: Your mockup is insufficient to diagnose your real problem.

Comment: Agreed with Don, I don't see the problem with the code. Maybe you have other code that can modify `myArray`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
private void readArray() {
    ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int a = 0; a <= _height - 1; a++) {
        row.clear();
        row = myArray.get(a);
        ...
    }
}
```

At the start of each iteration, you're clearing the `ArrayList` you were looking at in the last iteration. Why would you do that?

Just get rid of the `row.clear()` call, and I'd expect everything to be fine. I'd also suggest using the rather more idiomatic:

```
for(int a = 0; a < _height; a++) {
```

Or even better:

```
for(int a = 0; a < myArray.size(); a++) {
```

Or even *better*:

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> row : myArray) {
    ...
}
```

(Then you don't need to call `myArray.get()` at all!)

Comment: I thought so too, but then I read `I'm able to read it once and everything is there`.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg: No, that's exactly the point - he clears it *after* reading it, so it'll only fail the *next* time `readArray` is called. It's like reading a book, but rubbing out each page immediately after you've read it. Next time you come to read the book, it's blank!

Comment: With that interpretation, yes, definately. (+1 for not missing the obvious)

Comment: Also, the last array isn't empty because the loop would terminate before the last row.clear() can be performed, which is why it is the only one not empty.

Comment: row is just a throw away array. i clear it for the next loop so I dont get duplicates.

Comment: @bwoogie, that is not how Java handles references.  You are not getting a "copy" of the array (which you have to "throw away"), you are getting a reference to the originally created array.  That is why you are "losing" all your objects, because you are deleting the original contents.

Comment: No, row is initially an empty array, then you replace it with a reference to the one in your list. Then, before updating the reference, you carefully wipe out the values in the previous list.

Comment: ok, but my original array is "myArray" and i'm not clearing that and it is what's getting items removed from...

Comment: ok removing clear did fix it.. i guess i need to do some more studying on the java language.

Comment: row = myArray.get(a);

This does not copy the data there, it makes row a reference to the data there. When you call row.clear(), the row object is the same as the one in your list.

Comment: @bwoogie: Yes - it's absolutely *crucial* that you understand how objects work in Java. You should get a good book on Java, which covers this in detail.